# Diazo Rules execute for certain users not others?

Tags: plone, diazo

I am in the process of fine-tuning a Diazo theme. The server we are developing the site on contains multiple Plone sites, at the root of this server I have a user account which enables me manager access to each sub-site without having to create a user account for myself each time I create a new Plone site.

I am experiencing a problem in which when I log into the site I am developing (running the theme in question) - it executes all the rules fine, but if I make a standard user on this development site and log in.. The rules do not execute. I am basing the 'logged in' rule on the existance of the `#user-name` element which only appears after a user is logged into the site, I can confirm this element exists on the page both when I log in as the standard user, or my administrator account.

Rules:

```
<rules css:if-content="#user-name">
 <prepend theme="/html/head" content="/html/head/link"/>
 <append theme="/html/head" content="/html/head/script"/>
 <append theme="/html/head">
  <link href="/eatonbray/++theme++eatonbray/style/editing.css" type="text/css"
   rel="stylesheet" />
 </append>
 <replace css:theme-children="#main-content" css:content="#portal-column-content"/>
 <drop css:content="#portal-column-content" attributes="class"/>
</rules>
```

Does anyone know why they do not execute for a normal user account, even though the element exists?

Comment: I have to admit, I am not using Diazo much. Oldschoolwise I'd add a condition in the css-registry, to check for the actual given permission of the user and not only for a given css-id in the output. Is that possible for you with Diazo, too?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do what you speak of with Diazo, although as it turns out this question was a hasty post. It turned out to be stupidity on my part (refreshing the wrong site) embarrassing enough.

Comment: No prob, thanks for clearing this out, anyway!

Comment: P.S.: As expected, the condition-expression can be applied to the stylesheet-registration with Diazo in the same way as without Diazo.

Comment: Actually it would be better to close the question, could you press the button for it, please? TIA, Ida

Comment: I don't believe I have enough rep to do that, if anyone with rep sees this feel free to close!

Comment: Oh ok, I thought the owner of a quest can always do that. Thanks for quick reply, anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing the correct site is the answer to this, there is nothing wrong with the rules above.